# What are the English expressions for the questions which you have to answer and race to be the first to answer？

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

In a contest, there are some questions that each contestant has to answer, and some of the questions do not need to be answered by every contest, and they are  answered by the contestant who is the first one presses the button after the question was released.

For the first type of question, what is the authentic name for it? Can I say "required questions"?

As for the second one, can I use "quick response questions"?

I want to know the authentic expressions for it.

Answer (score 2):

A commonly used expression for the phase of a quiz show where the first contestant to buzz in is allowed to answer is the "[lightning round](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightning_round)".

Answer (score 2):

I think you're on the right track. I assume you plan to use these terms in a set of written instructions which may also be read out loud.

*"Required questions"* works perfectly, especially in a written form. You could also use the word *'mandatory.'*

Example: "The first twelve are *required questions*."

You could also say, "*Answers are required* for the first twelve questions."

*"Quick response questions"* works fine but doesn't entirely convey that the contestants are competing to be the first to respond. A fast paced oral contest calls these questions *"the lightning round"* and instruct that "the first correct answer wins" or "the first to respond correctly wins." You could also call them *"competitive questions"* but *"lightning round"* is very common for buzzing in an answer.

Comment: It's spelled "lightning", but this is a good answer. +1 :)